# How to handle one-to-many relations in a blade template?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, eloquent

I have two tables, concessionaire and bills. concessionaire has many bills but I only want to get the latest bill for previous bill purpose. Can you help me how can I do it?

Here is my template

```
@foreach($dataUser as $User)
  <tr class="item{{$User->id}}">
    <td>{{$User->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$User->bill->newrec}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

and my model is

```
public function bill()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Monthlybill', 'meternum', 'meternum');
    }
```

and in my controller

```
$dataUser = Concessionaire::with('user','rate', 'bill')
        ->get();
        //dd($dataUser);
        return view('reader.concessionaires',compact('dataUser'));
```

Right now that is my code but I do not know how can I get the latest bill record.

Comment: If a `Concessionaire` has many `Bill`s, you can't call something like  `$concessionaire->bill->newrec`, as `$concessionaire->bill` is a `Collection` and not a single `Bill`

Comment: how can I get the last value of the newrec field?

Comment: What is `Bill->newrec`? Is it a property? A relationship?

Comment: It is a property 

<td>{{$User->bill->newrec}}</td> in a relationship bill

Answer (score 1):

Use [last](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-last) helper

```
{{$User->bill->last()}}//this will give you the last items in collection
```

Comment: how can I get the last value of the specific field?

Comment: `$field->values->last()`

Comment: I do not get :( 

{{$User->bill->newrec->last()}}   still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
{{$User->bill->last()->newrec}}
```

Thanks!